# Install gcc compiler on Mac OS X 10.6

Tags: macos, gcc

I am using Xcode 3.2 on OS X 10.6.8. However I need a more recent gcc compiler (for C++).
Is there a chance to download it and install it in my case?
If that's possible how?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the Homebrew project.  This is designed for precisely the kind of thing you are trying to do without having to go through the (enormously) painful process of satisfying all of the dependencies yourself:

http://brew.sh

Comment: But how to set the new compiler installed with brew the default one in XCode?
And what is the file to change to set it as default in general?